# Error when trying to load words from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have this problem where my words of JSON won't load into my Webpage, the images do work already, fortunally..

I already have the images that needed to be loaded trough JSON into my Webpage.
I still need some words to load trough JSON into my Webpage,

```
{"main_object": {
    "imagesJ": ["beak", "cat", "egg", "meel", "milk", "passport", "spoon", "thee"],
    "wordsJ": ["næb", "kat", "æg", "mel", "mælk", "pas", "ske", "te"]
}
}
```

```js
var jsonData = "noJson";
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

$(document).ready(function(){
var jsonData = 'empty';
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "./js/data.json",
    dataType: 'html',
      success: function(response){
        jsonData = JSON.parse(response);

        console.log('ok');
          imagesJ = jsonData.main_object.imagesJ;
          wordsJ = jsonData.main_object.wordsJ;

          for(i = 0; i < imagesJ.length; i++) {
            images.innerHTML += '<img src="/sleepopdracht/img/'+imagesJ[i]+'.jpg" alt="images" id="'+[i]+'">';
          }
          document.getElementById('images') = html;

           for (i = 0; i < wordsJ.length; i++) {
              wordsJ.innerHTML += '<span>' + wordsJ[i] + '</span>';  
           }
             document.getElementById('words') = html;

      },
      error: function(){
        console.log('JSON could not be loaded.');
      }
    });
        console.log(jsonData);


});
```

```css
header {
  height: 5%;
}

body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.container {
  height: 90%;
}
.images img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
footer{
  height: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sleepopdracht</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>

  </header>

    <div class="container" id="container"><div class="images" id="images"></div>
                                          <div class="words" id="words"></div>
    </div>


  <footer>
  </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the Javascript you can see that I loaded the words a little like the images, as far as I know it should just work, but the console reports an

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment ~ jquery.min.js:4

I can't seem to figure out te source of the problem, neighter do I know how to solve it full.

It seems that The error exists even if i commend the **Words loop** out, The Error existed already without the code calling the **words JSON**. But now the problem still is that I can't find the source of the problem, if I found it, it is probably easy to solve. Since the last time I checked, the code ran perfectly without the **Words Loop**

Comment: [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is a property of DOM [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). You **cannot** use it with strings such as your `imagesJ`, `wordsJ`

Comment: But it does work perfectly fine with the images.. How can that be.. (I have still so much to learn)

Comment: You used `images.innerHtml` and there `images` may be a dom element, But `WordsJ` is a object property

Comment: Try using `imagesJ` instad of `images` and you'll get the same error. Might help to understand it  better. And I'm not sure where `images` even came from in the above code?

Comment: @EdisGolubich The images comes from Html, where the final product is supposed to be :s

But what you said does seem quite logically, although now I changed that, it still shows the same Error..

Answer (score 0):

I see that you havn't defined imagesJ and wordsJ

```
var imagesJ;
var wordsj;
```

And you need to do something like this

```
   var word = document.getElementById('words');
   var html = '';
   for (i = 0; i < wordsJ.length; i++) {
      html += '<span>' + wordsJ[i] + '</span>';  
   }
   word.innerHTML = html;
```

Final File

```
var jsonData = "noJson";
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var imagesJ;
var wordsj;

$(document).ready(function(){
var jsonData = 'empty';
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "./js/data.json",
    dataType: 'html',
      success: function(response){
        jsonData = JSON.parse(response);

        console.log('ok');
          imagesJ = jsonData.main_object.imagesJ;
          wordsJ = jsonData.main_object.wordsJ;

          for(i = 0; i < imagesJ.length; i++) {
            images.innerHTML += '<img src="/sleepopdracht/img/'+imagesJ[i]+'.jpg" alt="images" id="'+[i]+'">';
          }
          document.getElementById('images') = html;

        var word = document.getElementById('words');
        var html = '';
        for (i = 0; i < wordsJ.length; i++) {
            html += '<span>' + wordsJ[i] + '</span>';  
        }
        word.innerHTML = html;
      },
      error: function(){
        console.log('JSON could not be loaded.');
      }
    });
        console.log(jsonData);


});
```

Comment: I tried to use this, but it show's another error, and nothing will show up anymore, you sure this is right?

Comment: Is it still an errer from  ~ jquery.min.js:4 ?

Comment: Yes it is still the same error, I've tried the other answer too, and the comment section, nothing seems to work.. like usual with my codes xD..

Comment: Try console.log(wordsJ) maybe its going wrong there

Comment: it answers the console log with the right values, it knows it exists, but it doesnt load it into the browser..

Comment: "document.getElementById('words').innerHTML = '<span>' + wordsJ[0] + '</span>;" try this in the console

Comment: http://prntscr.com/algkbf

Is that supposed to happen? or did you do the '' "" wrong like Dimitry always does..

Comment: document.getElementById('words').innerHTML = '<span>' + wordsJ[0] + '</span>'; sorry

Comment: It didn't work with the ; at the end so i deleted that one, and now it shows me this, http://prntscr.com/algnpx I think this is okay. What can you do with this information, and what are you looking for (if more convenient for you you can explain in Dutch.)

Comment: hmmm and if you command out the words loop je dont get that error?

Comment: now you say that.. I do actually..

Although the error is after the console.log('ok');

Comment: No that is the problem idk where there error is comming from

Comment: :( I cry.. Thanks for helping tho!

Comment: Hope you will find out whats going wrong, Happy programming :D

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this code:

```
      for (i = 0; i < wordsJ.length; i++) {
          wordsJ.innerHTML += '<span>' + wordsJ[i] + '</span>';  
       }
      document.getElementById('words') = html;
```

to:

```
 var words = document.getElementById('words')
 for (i = 0; i < wordsJ.length; i++) {
     words.innerHTML += '<span>' + wordsJ[i] + '</span>';  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was in

```
 document.getElementById('images') = html;
```

this was wrong, first I didn't call html at all so I made a var after console log of html with an empty string.

```
      console.log('ok');
       var imagesJ = jsonData.main_object.imagesJ;
       var wordsJ = jsonData.main_object.wordsJ;
       var html = '';
       var html2 = '';
```

The var html2 is for the words.

then my `document.getElementById` was not complete (that was the Error)

This was the proper code for the document.

`document.getElementById('images').innerHTML = html;`

Then I had,

`images.innerHTML += '<img src="/sleepopdracht/img/'+imagesJ[i]+'.jpg" alt="images" id="'+[i]+'">';`

wich needed to be this,

`html += '<img src="/sleepopdracht/img/'+imagesJ[i]+'.jpg" alt="images" id="'+[i]+'">';`

So my full code then was,

```
  var jsonData = "noJson";
  var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   $(document).ready(function(){
   var jsonData = 'empty';
   $.ajax({
   async: false,
   url: "./js/data.json",
   dataType: 'html',
   success: function(response){
    jsonData = JSON.parse(response);

    console.log('ok');
      var imagesJ = jsonData.main_object.imagesJ;
      var wordsJ = jsonData.main_object.wordsJ;
      var html = '';
      var html2 = '';

      for(i = 0; i < imagesJ.length; i++) {
        html += '<img src="/sleepopdracht/img/'+imagesJ[i]+'.jpg" alt="images" id="'+[i]+'">';
        //images.innerHTML += '<img    src="/sleepopdracht/img/'+imagesJ[i]+'.jpg" alt="images" id="'+[i]+'">';
        }
        document.getElementById('images').innerHTML = html;
        //$('#images').append(html);


        for (i = 0; i < wordsJ.length; i++) {
          words.innerHTML += '<span>'+wordsJ[i]+'</span>';
         }
        document.getElementById('words').innerHTML = html2;

    },
    error: function(){
      console.log('JSON could not be loaded.');
    }
  });
      console.log(jsonData);


});
```

Altough I still don't have the words in my browser, the Error is resolved.
Thanks Everyone :D Happy programming!